# OpenID PHP Library Janrain, and setting the Auth_OpenID_RAND_SOURCE to null

Tags: php, openid, janrain

I was looking into using OpenID for an upcoming project I was going to be working on. After reading through some tutorials on Janrain's PHP implementation of OpenID and looking through the source code I uploaded it to my server and tested out the example script included with my Google ID and I was getting some errors about the Auth_OpenID_RAND_SOURCE in CryptUtil.php not being set properly. I found an answer through Google to define it as null instead of the default /dev/urandom. My question is, this obviously isn't safe right? and is /dev/urandom a random number generator in linux? What would be some good alternatives to using /dev/urandom on my home windows machine for messing around with the implementation?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the CryptUtil.php says that the class

```
     * Attempts to use a cryptographically secure (not predictable)
     * source of randomness if available. If there is no high-entropy
     * randomness source available, it will fail. As a last resort,
     * for non-critical systems, define
     * Auth_OpenID_RAND_SOURCE as null, and
     * the code will fall back on a pseudo-random number generator.
```

So, if you define this constant to NULL, AND it's unable to find any other source of entropy, this will mean you have no entropy source at all - basically, there will be no encryption. Here is what [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random) has to say about /dev/urandom:

> A counterpart to /dev/random is /dev/urandom ("unlocked"/non-blocking random source[4]) which reuses the internal pool to produce more pseudo-random bits. This means that the call will not block, but the output may contain less entropy than the corresponding read from /dev/random. The intent is to serve as a cryptographically secure pseudorandom number generator. This may be used for less secure applications.

As for entropy sources on Win32, there don't seem to be a lot of good options available to your PHP userland.